# Logging in Apache Zeppelin

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I would like to send the output of a cell to a file in the cluster, or at least print lines to such file.

I tried using log4j, when I try to set the file path with appender but it says appender is not a member of package org.apache.log4j.